# height of block using parallax

Tags: jquery

i try to make parallax background of a certain div, its almost good but when i scroll down, the height of div is not 100% , and it doesnt start from the very bottom of screen. Here is the website hurompolska.pl , u can see there before it reaches the red backgrounded div there's white space . How can i get rid of that white space ? 
For parallax effect i use this

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
parallax();
});
function parallax(){
var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
$('#cechy').css('background-Cposition-y',-(scrolled*0.2)+'px');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the height of your page in javascript, before you put anything on the page (like just after the body tag)

```
var bodyHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

This will give you the height of your browser window in px.  You can then set the height of your element to this.

If this doesn't work, my company and I created a list of parallax tutorials at http://potentpages.com/parallax-tutorials/ One of the tutorials here may be able to help you more thoroughly. You will probably want to look at the [jQuery section](http://potentPages.com/parallax-tutorials/#jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply.

However, i managed to do this without jquery , just css using:  background-size:cover